# Xcode 10: Big icon in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode10

I'm seeing the biggest image in the storyboard, despite having all 3 sizes in the assets, this only happens after installing Xcode 10 and Majove Update MacOS.

I just updated my Xcode to 10.0, suddenly all UIImageView and UIButton icons take the biggest one (3x). How can I go back to see a "REAL" preview when designing on the storyboard?

*In the Storyboard:*

[image: In the Storyboard]

*In the emulator:*

[image: In the emulator]

Thanks!

Comment: This happens to me also, after I upgraded to 10.1 and mojave. It happens only to the ones without explicit size constraints so the intrinsic content size is somehow messed.

Answer (score 0):

On your stroyboard, Try to change your imageview contentmode to AspectFill

Comment: Thank you for responding, but this also happens in the UIButton and basically in all the previsions in the storyboard, you should take the 2x but take the 3x. This only happens after updating to Xcode 10. :(

Comment: According this document https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/  iPhone8 uses 2x size image.